# Geometric Progression, Finding 3 Consecutive Unknown Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the three consecutive terms of geometric progression where the sum and product of these terms are 65 and 3375.

> $x+y+z=65$
>
> $xyz=3375$

How else do I approach this problem ?

Comment: Let the terms be $a/r,a$ and $ar$ with common ratio $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$a\cdot aq\cdot aq^2=3375$$
$$a+aq+aq^2=65$$
from here we get $$aq=15$$ and with this $$15(1+q+q^2)=65q$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Write $x=a, y=ar, z=ar^2$. Then you transform it to a system of equations with 2 unknowns.

In particular you will get: $a(1+r+r^2) = 65$ and $(ar)^3 = 3375 \implies ar = 15$

Multiply the first equation with the second and you will get $15a(1+r+r^2) = 65ar \implies 3 + 3r + 3r^2 = 13r$

Solve the equation for $r$ and track back to get the values of $a$ and $x,y,z$